# check if the rows from a set of indices are duplicates or not and reconstruction

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, indexing, unique

I have a 2D binary array where the value can take 0 and 1 only.
I have a set of indices to check whether the entries of the binary matrix for those indices are duplicate or not. I want to get the matrix with duplicate rows removed and the set of duplicate indices.

For example,

```
>>>> a
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
])
```

I am given set of indices (0,2,3,4,6,7).  From the set, the rows corresponding to (0,2) and (4,6,7) are duplicates.  I want the resulting matrix with the duplicates removed (as shown below)

```
>>>> b
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
])
```

and a method for reconstruction of the matrix 'a' from 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order in the output array is not relevant, then you can probably just use [Eelco Hoogendoorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516799). However, if you want to keep the same relative order as in the original array, here is another possible approach.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
])
idx = np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7])
# Make an array of row numbers
r = np.arange(len(a))
# Replace row numbers in idx with -1
# (use assume_unique only if indices in idx are unique)
r[np.isin(r, idx, assume_unique=True)] = -1
# Add the column to the array
a2 = np.concatenate([a, r[:, np.newaxis]], axis=-1)
# Find unique indices and inverse indices
_, uniq_idx, inv_idx = np.unique(a2, return_index=True, return_inverse=True, axis=0)
# Sort indices to make output array and inverse indices
s = np.argsort(uniq_idx)
a_uniq = a[uniq_idx[s]]
inv_idx = s[inv_idx]
print(a_uniq)
# [[1 0 1 0]
#  [0 0 1 1]
#  [0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 0]
#  [1 1 1 0]]
print(np.all(a_uniq[inv_idx] == a))
# True
```

EDIT: Some further explanation.

The idea in the solution above is to apply `np.unique`, but in a way that the rows that are not included in `idx` are not affected by it. In order to do that, you can just add a new number to each row. For the rows included in `idx`, this number will always be `-1`, and for the rest of rows it will be a different number for each. That way, it is impossible that rows that are not in `idx` get removed by `np.unique`. In order to do that, I build `r`, first with `np.arange(len(a))`, which gives you a number per row:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Then I check which of those are in `idx` with `np.isin(r, idx, assume_unique=True)` (`assume_unique` can only be used if elements in `idx` are guaranteed to be unique), so `r[np.isin(r, idx, assume_unique=True)] = -1` will turn all indices `idx` into -1:

```
[-1  1 -1 -1 -1  5 -1 -1]
```

That is added as new column to `a` into `a2`:

```
[[ 1  0  1  0 -1]
 [ 0  0  1  1  1]
 [ 1  0  1  0 -1]
 [ 0  0  1  1 -1]
 [ 1  1  1  0 -1]
 [ 1  1  1  0  5]
 [ 1  1  1  0 -1]
 [ 1  1  1  0 -1]]
```

Now it's just a matter of applying `np.unique` to `a2`. As expected, only rows in `idx` may be eliminated. However, since we want to keep the original relative order, we cannot use the output of `np.unique`, because it is sorted. We use `return_index` and `return_inverse` to get the indices that make the array of unique rows and the indices that get you back to the original array, and actually discard the new array.

To form the final array, you need to sort `uniq_idx` to keep the relative order, and then `inv_idx` accordingly. `np.argsort` gives you the indices that sort `uniq_idx` into `s`. `uniq_idx[s]` is just the array of unique row indices sorted, and `s[inv_idx]` will map every inverse index in `inv_idx` to the corresponding one in the resorted array. So, finally, `a[uniq_idx[s]]` gives you the output array, and the new `inv_idx` takes you back to the original one.

Comment: @Shew I have added some more explanations, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you could phrase your question at a higher level to get a more elegant solution; but this seems to solve the literal problem as stated.

```
idx = [0,2,3,4,6,7]
b = np.concatenate([np.unique(a[idx], axis=0), np.delete(a, idx, axis=0)], axis=0)
```